# Does the admissions committee contact potential supervisors again if they start considering waitlisted students?

Tags: phd, advisor, application

A professor showed interest in my PhD application (Australia, educational sciences) several months ago. He interviewed and recommended me. However, the university kept my application for the next round, telling me that they did not have enough time to review my case so they wanted to review it for the next round. I assumed this meant being waitlisted. Now we are getting close to the release date of this round (two weeks to go). If they consider my case again more seriously, will they contact this professor to ask whether he is still interested?

I ask because I want to know if I need to contact him again and express that I remain interested. Or is the fact that my application is still lodged in their system (I had the option to email them and withdraw it), proof enough that I am still considering them?

Answer (score 3):

This is likely going to be very specific to the specific university. However, you don't lose anything by contacting the professor in question again to express that you are still interested.